# Rails 4.2 + PG - Unable to initialize ActiveRecord objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple AR model:

```
class Purchaser < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :name
  has_many :purchases

  def initialize(opts={})
    @name = opts[:name]
  end
end
```

In a rails runner script, when I try to create a new Purchaser, I'm getting a transaction error.

```
purchaser = Purchaser.find_or_create_by(
  name: "Foo"
)
```

Here is the error:

```
activerecord-4.2.0.beta1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:373:in `clear_transaction_record_state': undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from activerecord-4.2.0.beta1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:304:in `ensure in rollback_active_record_state!'
from activerecord-4.2.0.beta1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:304:in `rollback_active_record_state!'
from activerecord-4.2.0.beta1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:283:in `save'
from activerecord-4.2.0.beta1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:34:in `create'
from activerecord-4.2.0.beta1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:141:in `block in create'
from activerecord-4.2.0.beta1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:300:in `scoping'
from activerecord-4.2.0.beta1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:141:in `create'
from activerecord-4.2.0.beta1/lib/active_record/relation.rb:211:in `find_or_create_by'
from activerecord-4.2.0.beta1/lib/active_record/querying.rb:6:in `find_or_create_by'
```

What am I doing wrong? Ruby 2.1.2, PostgreSQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding the `initialize` method in ActiveRecord. You should call `super` to execute the ActiveRecord (parent) constructor as well. You could do it after you execute your code. Something like:

```
def initialize(opts={})
   @name = opts[:name]
   super
end
```

Hope this helps.